# Directory view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, directory, treeview, hierarchy

I've been working in an app and wanted to create a directory view in which we can access folders/sub-folders and blocks within the directory. It also allows dragging of files into the folder.

Here's the picture which will explain it better
[image: Here's the picture which will explain it better]

I've searched the packages which might relates to it e.g. [Flutter Tree View.](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_treeview) But I don't know if its supports dragging of widgets into folder. I wanted to know if there's a better way to achieve this goal and create the view just like in the picture where we can have parent node view and children node views and also allows dragging of node at any level into another node level?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from scratch using the FileSystemEntites returned by `Directory(directoryPath).list();` (`dart:io`) in a ListView and apply the interactivity using the flutter `Draggable` or the flutter `Dismissible` Widgets for the file/folder interaction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but one thing I forgot to add is that this view doesn't reflect internal/external storage of the device, its basically the view of library we are getting from an API, the folders are used as an organizer for the blocks. I suppose it'll still work for it ?

Comment: @TalhaGondal yes, as long as you can supply the blocks' names as strings to for example a `ListView` the idea remains the same. Instead of `Directory(directoryPath).list();` you just use your API to get the data you need.